# chrome extension using google.payments.inapp fails

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to enable in-app purchase inside my chrome extension. For that I've integrated with Google's [buy.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/managed-in-app-payments/scripts/buy.js) lib.
Now when I attempt to purchase using this endpoint - `google.payments.inapp.buy`

I get the following error -

> An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later.

When I look at the console of the prompted paymet screen I see that there's a failed attempt to call a service at url -

> https://224.32.32.55/29753 Failed to load resource:
>   net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

It used to work in the past and stopped. What could be causing this?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same. Not with in-app purchases, but with the one-time $5 payment to unlock my developer account. Seems to be widespread as I see the same issue in many forums. I've tried with 3 different Google Accounts, on different network/ISPs. No solution so far! If I find one, I'll report back here...